# How to host kubernetes cluster on VPN comprising of VM's from different cloud providers

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openvpn

What I am trying to accomplish here is, create a k8s cluster but the worker & master nodes are in different cloud. 
 
Example, I have a VM instance in AWS & another one in GCP.
 I can't use them as master & worker node because they are not on the same network range.
My question, is it be possible to create a VPN which comprises of these machines & then host a k8s cluster on top of it so that I can use different machines in different cloud as my worker/master nodes. 
Or there is some fundamental flaw in my understanding of k8s

I don't want to use IP-Sec or DRG which are not part of free tier to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

A number of Kubernetes Container Network Interface (CNI) plugins support overlay networks. An overlay network creates tunnels on a real network for the k8s nodes to communicate across physical subnets on what appears like a local interface.

- [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/backends.md) does VXLAN (UDP)
- [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/determine-best-networking) does IPIP or VXLAN

There are a number of issues you will need to tackle with a geographically disperse cluster.

- How you schedule you application across the cluster appropriately.
- How the nodes communicate with masters.
- How your etcd cluster is structured.

The common solution to these problems is to run multiple clusters in each geo location and traffic manage them.

Comment: currently I am using calico & as suggested by you it creates a tunnel on real network. My question is that can this real network be a VPN network onto which I create master & worker nodes. Also regarding scheduling & other issues, if I can host k8s cluster then k8s master would deploy application/pods on worker nodes. For an instance we can assume that using kubeadm I am hosting control plane on 1 machine which has etcd & all controllers.

Comment: Yeah, a network is a network. As long as the source and destination IP of the tunnel is routed via the VPN. You will be tunneling inside a tunnel, so don't use TCP for the VPN and expect a bunch of MTU issues. But as a test bench with nodes on one side and master on the other should be fine. Nodes don't need perfect connectivity to the masters, they can survive without them and still serve their apps.

Comment: If this is purely a cost exercise then maybe try AKS. They give you the control plane for free.